# how to display pure css tooltip in container with overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

The css below displays a tooltip from a data attribute on hover but does not work for the use case when it is to display the whole data attribute when the container `td` has `overflow: hidden`.

Removing `overflow: hidden` enables the tooltip but destroys the ellipsis.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 64px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header,
.demo,
.demo p {
  margin: 4em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.name {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td class="name" data-tooltip="dsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd">dsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Seblor it's possible [since quite a time already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @Kaddath Ah, thank you. I'll admit I have never seen it used until now.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the text in a `<p>` tag and add the `overflow:hidden` to that instead?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 64px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header,
.demo,
.demo p {
  margin: 4em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[data-tooltip]:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  /*width: 160px;*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

.name {}

p {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 200px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td class="name" data-tooltip="dsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd">
      <p>dsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd</p>
    </td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would also suggest not limiting the width of the tooltip (`[data-tooltip]:before`) as it will cut off your text. I've amended the example above to comment the width out.

Comment: it is a good idea unfortunately, I need to set the `max-length: 0` on the td so it expands out to the the whole td.  Having max-length: 0 on the p makes it not visible

Comment: @dagda1 sorry not sure what you mean - why do you need 'max-length: 0'? Could you update your code with this?